# How to use CSS images with Vite?

Tags: css, background-image, vite

Vite doesn't seem able to resolve paths for CSS `url()`. I have:

```
.element {
  background-image: url("../assets/images/my-image.png");
}
```

Instead of seeing the resolved path in Chrome, I just see the same unresolved path I specified in my CSS ("../assets/images/my-image.png") which is of course meaningless for Chrome.

How to make it work?